# How to create a joystick for camera control

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

Hey I am trying to build a joystick which is well understood and can be used by elders. The joystick need to have 4 directions: Left,Right,Top and Down and also has a pause button in the middle.
This joystick is need to be used for moving a camera.
I have found a code in the web which create for me an svg joystick.

The problem is that this joystick isn't easy to used ,and when you pressed on a direction you don't know if you click on it or not.
Also when you click on the center for stop action you don't have a feedeback for clicking.

I am looking for alternative or improvement for my current joystick.
How can I improve my current controller so I will have a feedback for clicking in svg. Can I create a stick in svg so I will know to which direction I am pointing right now?
I would be happy if someone can help me with this controller,
thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
I need a real visual feedback for each arrow and the stop button. If any changes are required for current svg, it is welcome.

```css
#arrowRight:hover,
#arrowLeft:hover,
#arrowDown:hover,
#arrowUp:hover{
  fill:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="joystick" style="width:20%">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(16,16,16);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(240,240,240);stop-opacity:1" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(240,240,240);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(16,16,16);stop-opacity:1" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="grad3" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(168,168,168);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(239,239,239);stop-opacity:1" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#grad1)" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47" fill="url(#grad2)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.5px" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="44" fill="url(#grad3)" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="#cccccc" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px"  />
    <path id="arrowUp" d="M50,14 54,22 46,22Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"   />
    <path id="arrowDown" d="M50,86 54,78 46,78Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"  />
    <path id="arrowLeft" d="M14,50 22,54 22,46Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"  />
    <path id="arrowRight" d="M86,50 78,54 78,46Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)"  />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use the CSS3 perspective property: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp

Comment: I need to support IE9 in my product so I can't use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `onclick` function to each path. Send the direction as a parameter to this function.

```js
function click(elem, direction) {
  var arrows = document.getElementsByClassName("arrow");
  //reset all arrows
  for (let i = 0; i < arrows.length; i++) {
    arrows[i].style.fill = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
  }
  //Set the clicked arrow to red
  elem.style.fill = "red";
};
```

```css
#arrowRight:hover,
#arrowLeft:hover,
#arrowDown:hover,
#arrowUp:hover {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="joystick" style="width:20%">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(16,16,16);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(240,240,240);stop-opacity:1" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="grad2" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(240,240,240);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(16,16,16);stop-opacity:1" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="grad3" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(168,168,168);stop-opacity:1" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(239,239,239);stop-opacity:1" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="url(#grad1)" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="47" fill="url(#grad2)" stroke="black" stroke-width="1.5px" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="44" fill="url(#grad3)" />
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="#cccccc" stroke="black" stroke-width="1px" />
    <path id="arrowUp" class="arrow" d="M50,14 54,22 46,22Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)" onclick="click(this, 'up')" />
    <path id="arrowDown" class="arrow" d="M50,86 54,78 46,78Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)" onclick="click(this,'down')" />
    <path id="arrowLeft" class="arrow" d="M14,50 22,54 22,46Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)" onclick="click(this,'left')" />
    <path id="arrowRight" class="arrow" d="M86,50 78,54 78,46Z" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0.8)" onclick="click(this,'right')" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I have already have an onclick event in my code, I need a visual feedback for the user so he could now that he pressed left. My user won't look in the console messages,I am talking about users which aren't programmers.

Comment: thanks but this isn't what I was looking for, it is very hard to see this red feedback, I am looking for more visual feedback on the button himself. maybe a resize of the arrow and so on.

Comment: I think Brk needs a designer. This is not the right plattform for that.

Comment: @Brk Oh ok. Your question was not clear about this. You were just asking for a feedback. I won't be able to help you for a more *real* visual feedback